# Замена значения из списка

Tags: python

Как заменить nan на 5 в списке `q = [nan,10,nan,nan]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаемо, что `nan` это `float('nan')`

```
import math

q = [float('nan'), float('nan'), 10, float('nan'), 9]    
[ 5 if math.isnan(i) else i for i in q]  # [5, 5, 10, 5, 9]
```